# Combinatorics problem: coefficient of $x^k$ in $(x + x^2 + x^3 + ...)^n$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Define $f(n,k)$ with $k \geq n$ as the number of ways to colour $k$ identical objects with $n$ colours, such that every object has one colour and every colour is used at least once.

I want to prove that $f(n,k)$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(x + x^2 + x^3 + ...)^n$, I do not however, have any idea how to do this..

What I've done so far:

As another part of the exercise I've found that $f(n,k) = \binom{k - 1}{n - 1}$, but I don't see how that could help here. Any assistance would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hint: compute $f(n,k)$ for $n=1$, then $n=2.$  Think about how to relate the resulting expressions to the given generating function.

Comment: The coefficient of $x^k$ is determined by the number of ways $(x + x^2 + ..)^n$ can form $x^k$, right? So $x^2$ can be made only through $x \cdot x$, but $x^3$ through $x \cdot x^2$ and $x^2 \cdot x$, and thus has coefficient 2 (for $n = 2$).

Comment: yes, that's right.  You have $f(1,k)=1$ since the only thing to be done is use the single color for all $k$ objects.  You can see how this coefficient of $1$ arises in the generating function $(x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)^1.$  For $f(2,k)$ do you have a general formula?  You've got two colors at your disposal.  How many different ways to color $k$ objects?  You are correct that there is $1$ way if there are two objects and $2$ ways if there are three objects.  What about four, five, six objects?  Do you see how the generating function relates to your answer?

Comment: Well, since you know that every color is used once, (we don't use $x^0$), this boils down to the number of $x^i$ and $x^j$ with $i, j \geq 1$ such that $x^i \cdot x^j = x^k$. This equal to choosing $k$ elements from $n$ elements, only we exclude the two cases where only colour is used. I see now that if the number of colours increases, you exclude more cases, and I'll manage from here. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficient of $x^k$ in $(\sum_{j=1}^\infty x^j)^n$ can be found by considering how many ways you can get the term $x^k$ when you expand the product (since all the coefficients in the original summation polynomials are 1). If you consider this as a product of $n$ summation terms, the exponent of $x$ in the first summation term (call it $j_1$) and the exponent of $x$ in the second summation term (call it $j_2$) and so forth must all add up to $k$, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n j_i = k$. But since $x^1$ is the smallest power in each summation term, this is the same as choosing $n$ positive integers (where the ordering matters) that add up to be $k$. This is the bijection you need for your coloring problem: For each of the $n$ colors (where the colors are distinct so the ordering of colors matters) you choose a positive number of objects to color with that color, such that the total number of colored objects is $k$.

Comment: Ah, for me this is more intuitive than your first answer. I finally get it now. Thank you for helping me! (and sorry for being a pain and making you write out two answers :(.. )

Answer (score 1):

You can use your combinatorial combination coefficient formula ${k-1} \choose {n-1}$ you proved, in order to get the answer: It is the number of ways you can place $n-1$ identical sticks in between a sequence of $k$ stones such that sticks are placed in distinct positions so that the $k$ stones are split into $n$ groups of at least one stone each. In this bijection, the $m$th group from left-to-right corresponds to the $m$th color, and the number of stones in the $m$th group is the number of identical objects that are colored with color $m$. In order for this bijection to work with your coloring problem, you need that the ordering of the identical objects doesn't matter (which it seems like it doesn't since the objects are "identical").

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how this would correlate with $x^k$ in $(x + x^2 + x^3 + ...)^n$...

Comment: You  mentioned your proved ${k-1} \choose {n-1}$ as the answer so I thought that was fair game to use. I'll post another answer that shows the relation to the polynomial coefficient if you prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

The expansion you cite is easy:
\begin{align}
[z^k] (z + z^2 + \ldots)^n
  &= [z^{k - n}] \left( \sum_{r \ge 0} z^r \right)^n \\
  &= [z^{k - n}] (1 - z)^{-n} \\
  &= (-1)^{k - n} \binom{-n}{k - n} \\
  &= \binom{k - 1}{n - 1}
\end{align}